# Log user updates

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

In the making of a small community networking site, but I was seeking some advice as to how best to design a table that will store data to be pulled as a stream that shows for example:

```
User X has added a friend!
User Y has commented on a post!
User X changed their profile picture!
User X has changed their motto!
```

Currently this is my setup but before I continue wanted to know if I was on the right track

```
update_id  int PK
member_id  int FK
friend_id  int FK
update_action text
update_time   datetime
update_hidden  tinyint
```

At the moment I was planning to run an extra insert query to update this table with each activity when a user does it, not sure if that is the best or in my case a good way to get this done. Any tips or advice will be appreciated thanks for your time.

Comment: You could also add triggers for automated logging...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have an example to show? and would a trigger be more efficient in a sense?

Comment: First, you can create lookup table with standard user actions, and instead keeping `update_action` column in `update` table, you can keep foreign key to lookup table. Beside that foreign key, you can create new varchar(max) column to keep concrete text of commenting or posting...

Comment: So then I would have a another table with the actions already listed and use that PK as a FK in the update table that I currently have? Just to be sure I already have a table that stores the comments/posts but this table would be for displaying to the rest of the community what X user has done

Comment: Keeping `actions table` would be better, each action can be referenced via a `fk`. Update idea is not harmful. Otherwise you will need multiple self joins to check the changes happened to a user from the last time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a table for all the different activities that your system should offer.

```
CREATE TABLE activity
(
    id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description NVARCHAR(126) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

For example: has commented on a post, has a new friend, etc.

And then log all the activities that happen, depending on the id of the activity (so that you can manually define where in the code which activity should be used) and store it somehow like this:

```
CREATE TABLE activityLog
(
    id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userId UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    friendId UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    acitivityId UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    hidden TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(friendId) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(acitivityId) REFERENCES activity(id)
);
```

Assuming that you have your users stored in a table called 'users'.

Just make sure that It's easy to create new activities, easy to link the events, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) think this will help me out. But as for easy to link how do you mean exactly easy to link?

Comment: As in making it easy to reference ids and values from other tables; keep the database as isolated as needed, it will pay off. For example: it was very easy to "link" each activity in the example I gave you, because It easy easy to reference an unique id in another table.